# XAML templating data

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, datatemplate, windows-store

I have a `ListView` populated with three different types of items. When I select a `ListViewItem` in the `ListView` I want to display data in a template specifically designed for the type of the selected item.

The data is displayed in a different column in the same `Grid` as the `ListView`.

My question is, what element should I use to make new Templates for displaying the data for the selected item.

I was hoping it would be possible to set a sort of `ItemTemplate` property on a `Grid`, but that is not the case.

```
<Grid
    x:Name="ItemDetailsGrid"
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource {Binding SelectedItem.TemplateName}}">         
</Grid>
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to need a ContentPresenter

```
<ContentPresenter
   x:Name = "ItemDetailsGrid"
   Content = "{Binding SelectedItem}">
   <ContentPresenter.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DateType="{x:Type Type1}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyA}" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DateType="{x:Type Type2}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyB}" />
      </DataTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

The appropriate template will be chosen based on it's type.